# GMAP.NET WPF - Center Shape Around Point

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

I'm adding shapes to my WPF GMap.NET control with code such as the following:

```
System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(gMapControl1);
var point = gMapControl1.FromLocalToLatLng((int)p.X, (int)p.Y);
GMapMarker m = new GMapMarker(point);
m.Shape = new Rectangle
{
    Width = 10,
    Height = 10,
    Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red

};
m.Tag = "PolyDot";
gMapControl1.Markers.Add(m);
```

A problem that I'm experiencing is the shape is not centered on the point.  The shape's top left corner is normally where the point is.  How can I center the shape around the point?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  Actually super easy

```
GMapMarker m = new GMapMarker(point);
Rectangle recShape = new Rectangle
{
    Width = 100,
    Height = 100,
    Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red

};
m.Shape = recShape;
m.Tag = "PolyDot";
m.Offset = new Point(-recShape.Width / 2, -recShape.Height/2);
gMapControl1.Markers.Add(m);
```